# C++: Static variables in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

What is the problem with having static variables (especially within functions) in multithreaded programs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To pick an illustrative example at random, take an interface like [`asctime`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/asctime/) in the C library.  The prototype looks like this:

```
 char *
 asctime(const struct tm *timeptr);
```

This implicitly must have some global buffer to store the characters in the `char*` returned.  The most common and simple way to accomplish this would be something like:

```
 char *
 asctime(const struct tm *timeptr)
 {
    static char buf[MAX_SIZE];

    /* TODO: convert timeptr into string */

    return buf;
 }
```

This is totally broken in a multi-threaded environment, because `buf` will be at the same address for each call to `asctime()`.  If two threads call `asctime()` at the same time, they run the risk of overwriting each other's results.  Implicit in the contract of `asctime()` is that the characters of the string will stick around until the next call to `asctime()`, and concurrent calls breaks this.

There are some language extensions that work around this particular problem in this particular example via thread-local storage (`__thread`,`__declspec(thread)`).  I believe this idea made it into C++0x as the `thread_local` keyword.

Even so I would argue it's a bad design decision to use it this way, for similar reasons as for why it's bad to use global variables.  Among other things, it may be thought of as a cleaner interface for the caller to maintain and provide this kind of state, rather than the callee.  These are subjective arguments, however.

Answer (score 31):

Initialization is not thread-safe.  Two threads can enter the function and both may initialize the function-scope static variable. That's not good.  There's no telling what the result might be.

In C++0x, initialization of function-scope static variables will be thread-safe; the first thread to call the function will initialize the variable and any other threads calling that function will need to block until that initialization is complete.

I don't think there are currently any compiler + standard library pairs that fully implement the C++0x concurrency memory model and the thread support and atomics libraries.

Comment: Is it really likely that a compiler will initialize a static variable on the first call?  From what I have seen in the most commonly-used compilers, they are just treated like globals.  I just confirmed this for GCC looking at assembly output of some code that uses a `static int`...

Comment: @asveikau:  Certainly, any dynamic initialization that has side effects would definitely have to be done when the function is first called an no sooner.  In your example, if you have a `static int` initialized with a constant expression, there is no dynamic initialization and the object is initialized before the function is first entered.  (I didn't intend to write a treatise here on the many complications with static initialization; there are many, many details.  I only wanted to cover the most problematic case here.)

Comment: Some of the trouble is that I was thinking in C, where AFAIK you can't initialize a `static` with a non-constant expression.  I think you can do so in C++.

Comment: @asveikau:  You can in C++.  I don't know about C; I'm not nearly as familiar with C as I am with C++.

Answer (score 2):

A static variable usually means multiple invocations of your function would share a state and thus interfere with one another.

Normally you want your functions to be self contained; have local copies of everything they work on and share nothing with the outside world bar parameters and return values. (Which, if you think a certain way, aren't a part of the function anyway.)

Consider:

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

definitely thread-safe, local copies of x and y.

```
void print(const char *text, Printer *printer);
```

dangerous, someone outside might be doing something with the same printer, e.g. calling another print() on it.

```
void print(const char *text);
```

definitely non-thread-safe, two parallel invocations are guaranteed to use the same printer.

Of course, there are ways to secure access to shared resources (search keyword: `mutex`); this is just how your gut feeling should be.

Unsynchronized parallel writes to a variable are also non-thread-safe most of the time, as are a read and write. (search keywords: `synchronization`, `synchronization primitives` [of which `mutex` is but one], also `atomicity`/`atomic operation` for when parallel access is safe.)