# Lambda capture list and defined function pointer type

Tags: c++, lambda

The following code does not compile:

```
typedef void(*RunnableFun)(int);  //pointer-to-function type

void foo(RunnableFun f) {
}
void bar(const std::string& a) {
    foo([&](int) -> void { std::cout << a; });
}
```

and IntelliSense is telling me

> ```
> no suitable conversion function from "lambda []void (int)->void" to "RunnableFun" exists
> ```

and the compiler is complaining

> ```
>   'void foo(RunnableFun)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'bar::<lambda_796873cf40a6be4e411eb9df14f486bf>' to 'RunnableFun'
> ```

But the following does compile:

```
typedef void(*RunnableFun)(int);  //pointer-to-function type

void foo(RunnableFun f) {

}
void bar(const std::string&) {
    // Notice the empty capture list
    foo([](int) -> void { std::cout << "dummy"; });
}
```

How can I keep the signature of `foo()` but achieve what I tried in to in the first code example?

P.S.: Changing foo's signature to `void foo(std::function<void(int)> f)` would compile but can I do it without changing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to function only stores a location of execution, it stores no additional state.  The only change between executions must be determined by *global* state.

In your case, you want the lambda to capture *local* state.  So when called after `a="hello"` it prints a different value than when called after `a="world"`.

The short answer is "Too bad, so sad, but no".

You can hack a bit.  You could store `a` in a `static std::string ga;` and accessmit within the lambda.  Note that this is ugly, not reentrant, exposes your code to global state needlessly, and generally a bad idea.

```
void bar(const std::string& a) {
  static std::string ga;
  ga = a; // note, separate line
  foo([](int) -> void { std::cout << ga; });
}
```

Generally pure function pointer callback APIs are a sign an ignorant fool designed the API: a proper C-style callback takes a `void*`, and a proper C++ callback is a `std::function` or template callable or similar.  (Ignorant as they are not aware that the `void*` pattern is common: fool because even if you did not know of it, they did not work it out themselves after trying their system a few times and noticed the big gaping hole.  It is ok: most programmers are fools until they make *all* the mistakes themselves!)

If you *actually* have a `void*` or equivalent argument you get called back with, you omitted it from your question, and the answer is entirely different.  Just store a ptr-to-lambda in that `void*`, and store a stateless lambda that casts-and-calls the stateful lambda from the `void*`.

Comment: "*that casts-and-calls the stateful lambda from the `void*`*" I'm curious as to how exactly that would happen. After all, the type of a lambda is not known, so you'd need to use `decltype(some_variable)` to get it and perform the cast. So where do you get the variable? I think it'd be better to wrap the stateful lambda in a `std::function` and pass *that* as the `void*` in question. That way, you know exactly what type to cast it to.

Comment: @nicol `auto f=[&](int x){std::cout<<a<<'\n';};  foo( [](void* ptr, int x){ auto* pf = static_cast<decltype(f)*>(ptr); (*pf)(x); }, &f );`?  Or wrap the lambda-and-`void*` pattern into a class with a factory function that deduces the type of `F`?  Nothing fundamentally hard here, and you need to store the lambda somewhere, so `decltype` has a natural target (wherever it is).

Comment: Interesting hack, albeit not applicable for my [multithreaded application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4590776/1531708). Marked as answer because of its many details

Comment: @phillab in multi threaded, thread local storage can be used.

Answer (score 7):

You could take a look at most of the [standard library algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). When they take a "predicate" (callable object) they do it as a template arguments.

So you could make your function as a template:

```
template<typename FunctionType>
void foo(FunctionType f) {
}
```

No other change is needed.

It's either this or using `std::function`, you can't solve your problem without changing the `foo` function.